# How to convert properly char * const[256] to const char * const*

Tags: c, pointers, casting, constants, execv

I have this struct:

```
typedef struct cmdLine {
char * const arguments[256];
} cmdLine;
```

I also have an argument `cmdLine *pCmdLine`. I want to use `execv`so I write `execv((pCmdLine->arguments[0]),  pCmdLine->arguments);`. The second argument doesn't feet properly to `execv`and I want to ask how to convert it properly.

The warning I get is: *Passing 'char* const[256]'' to parameter of type 'const char *const *' discards qualifiers in nested pointer types*. I would lie for some help to convert it properly, thanks.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why can't you make it the appropriate type (`char const * const[256]`) to begin with?

Comment: Because `cmdLine` is a struct I got as a requirement to the project.

Comment: Interesting... the POSIX headers list the prototype for `execv` as *`int execv(const char *path, char *const argv[]);`* - what system are you targetting?

Comment: Windows 10 @AnttiHaapala

Comment: There is no `execve` in Windows 10, there is `_execve` which has `const char * const` suitable for C++

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not very familiar with the expresions so I didn't understand what you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any problems:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdio.h>

struct
{
char * const arr[20];
}*str;

void foo(char  *const par[])
{
    volatile const char * const ptr = par[4]; 
    printf("%s\n", par[7]);
    printf("%s\n", ptr);
}


void foo1()
{
    foo(str -> arr);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4Sv4a8